# How to increment the number in results[0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python/Tkinter program and I am trying to increment some numbers that are at the end of a variable used for tk.Entry boxes.

For example, self.output0, self.output1, self.output2, etc

(Sorry, my code is long so I tried shortening it up for an example.)

```
    self.entries = []
    self.output0 = tk.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
    self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=1)

    self.output1 = tk.Entry(self, width=149, justify='center', bd='0', bg='#E0E0E0')
    self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=1)
```

I grab the users input with another entry box such as 'self.first_entry' and run a SQL query on the user input.

For example:

```
class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def authenticate(self):
        return pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    def calculate(self):
        firstname = str(self.first_entry.get()) # converts user entry into variable
        lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
        license = str(self.lic_entry.get())

        try:
            connection = self.authenticate()
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.output0.delete(0, END)
                self.output0.insert(0,"You do not have access.") 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM MyTABLEName "   # table name
                "with (nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE ?")
            Values = [firstname + '%']
        else:
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM MyTABLEName "   # table name
                "(nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE ? AND LASTNAME LIKE ? AND LICNUMBER LIKE ?")
            Values = [firstname + '%', lastname + '%', '%' + license + '%']
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
        if results:
            self.output0.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output0.insert(0,results[0]) # enters results in entry
            self.output1.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output1.insert(0,results[1]) # enters results in entry
            self.output2.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output2.insert(0,results[2]) # enters results in entry
            self.output3.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output3.insert(0,results[3]) # enters results in entry
            self.output4.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output4.insert(0,results[4]) # enters results in entry
            connection.close()
        else:
            self.output0.delete(0, END)
            self.output0.insert(0,"There are no records for this input.")
```

The above will output 5 rows from the database.

I am wanting to shorten the code up.  How can I take the below and write it so that I do not have to repeat

```
            self.output0.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output0.insert(0,results[0]) # enters results in entry
            self.output1.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
            self.output1.insert(0,results[1]) # enters results in entry
            2
            2
            3
            3
            ...etc
```

I want to increment the outputX and the number in results[x]

This below is what I have been trying but it is not working:

```
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
    results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
    self.outputs =  [self.output0, self.output1, self.output2, self.output3, self.output4]
    for output in self.outputs:
        for i in range(0, 4):
            if results:
                output.delete(0, END)  # clears entry
                output.insert(0,results[i]) # enters results in entry
            else:
                self.output0.delete(0, END)
                self.output0.insert(0,"There are no records for this input.")
```

How can I increment the number in "resuls[x]" so that I get a different row from the SQL query?  It keeps printing the same row on each line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to index your cursor. Try converting it to a list first and then running the function.

```
results = list(cursor.fetchmany(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy and not so intrusive solution would be to use `getattr`:

```
def update_fields(self, prefix, values):
    for x, _ in enumerate(values):
        attr = getattr(self, prefix + str(x))
        attr.delete(0, END)
        attr.insert(0, values[x])
```

And then you'd just:

```
results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
if results:
    self.update_fields('output', results)
```

Please note that `getattr` will raise an `AttributeError` if `self` has no declared field named `outputX`

You can ignore undeclared fields by swallowing the exception:

```
def update_fields(self, prefix, values):
    for x, _ in enumerate(values):
        try:
            attr = getattr(self, prefix + str(x))
            attr.delete(0, END)
            attr.insert(0, values[x])
        except AttributeError:
            pass
            # You can also use continue
```

Comment: It would be best if you could remove all of the sql code, and replace it with some hard-coded data in the same format you get from your database.